# Does Flex clean up after itself before calling YY_FATAL_ERROR?

Tags: flex-lexer

Flex-generated lexers call the user-definable `YY_FATAL_ERROR()`.  Does Flex clean up any resources that it allocated itself before calling this macro/function? Does it release any allocated memory?

Is it generally possible to exit cleanly from a Flex-generated lexer when such an error occurs?

Comment: Are you sure `YY_FATAL_ERROR` is a real thing? I cannot find it in the manual https://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/download/flex.pdf

Comment: @PiotrSiupa You are right, it is not in the manual. But it is mentioned many times both in this tag [tag:flex-lexer] as well as mailing lists. Flex calls this macro on error, and expects that it won't return. Anyway, I looked at the Flex-generated sources and it's clear that there is no cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Flex-generated sources it becomes clear that there is no cleanup. For example, `yy_create_buffer()` contains this code:

```c
    YY_BUFFER_STATE b;
    
    b = (YY_BUFFER_STATE) yyalloc( sizeof( struct yy_buffer_state ) , yyscanner );
    if ( ! b )
        YY_FATAL_ERROR( "out of dynamic memory in yy_create_buffer()" );

    b->yy_buf_size = size;

    /* yy_ch_buf has to be 2 characters longer than the size given because
     * we need to put in 2 end-of-buffer characters.
     */
    b->yy_ch_buf = (char *) yyalloc( (yy_size_t) (b->yy_buf_size + 2) , yyscanner );
    if ( ! b->yy_ch_buf )
        YY_FATAL_ERROR( "out of dynamic memory in yy_create_buffer()" );
```

If allocating `b->yy_ch_buf` fails, `b` is not deallocated.

The default `YY_FATAL_ERROR` is `yy_fatal_error`, which just prints a message and calls `exit()`, so it does not do deallocation either.